# Automatic rescaling of images to a smaller preview window on web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm trying to make the images displayed in my grid windows on my webpage http://foottherapy.tumblr.com/ display as rescaled versions (i.e. the whole pic only resized for the grid window) instead of this partial representation. I've tried using modifying the attributes to heigh:100% or width:100% for those blocks but it didn't work.
Any help is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

yes. either adjust the div size to match the thumbnail, since you are using css `background-image` to load it, or load it in an `<img>` tag which will automatically adjust to the size of the image on the screen. alternatively you can use <`img height='200' width='200' />` to force scaling by the browser. the quality may not be as as good with browser scaling, so usually you want to prescale it using some software or code that does high quality scaling and respects the image ratios.

another alternative in css is to use the new css3 option: `background-size: 200px 50px`, but that's not really recommended if you want to show this to a wide audience.

Answer (score 0):

Use following: `<img src='...' style='width:200px;'/>` (200px - is an example, use what you need for your page). You can also limit the height by style='height:100px'. If you use both, it might distort an image (i.e. do not use both if you want to preserve the ratio).